# Flash player for Chrome or Chromium browsers on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, flash, adobe

I have checked many threads, but could not find a solution. I want to use Chrome or Chromium on Ubuntu 12.04. I have installed Adobe Flash plugin from the Ubuntu Software Center, but it only works for Firefox, not for Chrome or Chromium web browser.

I have also tried to install by .tar ball. placed .so file in chromium browser installation directory and usr folder in /usr, but all in vain.

Is there any other solution or am I missing something? My Ubuntu Software Center is not able to locate Pepper flash plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Pepper Flash Player is built-in with Google Chrome web browser, so it doesn't need to be installed separately. Google Chrome can play flash videos without installing any other software. Pepper Flash Player is not built-in with Chromium web browser, so it must be installed separately. Pepper Flash Player in Chromium is the same as the built-in flash player that Google Chrome uses.

To install Pepper Flash Player for Chromium in Ubuntu 12.04, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:skunk/pepper-flash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer
```

In order to configure Chromium to use Pepper Flash Player, open `/etc/chromium-browser/default` from the terminal in nano text editor using the command `sudo nano /etc/chromium-browser/default` and add the following line to the end of the file on a new line:

```
. /usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/pepflashplayer.sh
```

Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file being edited. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Restart Chromium, and load the `chrome://plugins` page to verify that the plugin is active.

Comment: When I enter last command it said:

E: Unable to locate package pepflashplugin-nonfree

Comment: I edited the last command. Try it that way.

Comment: @hmluqman If it's working you should accept the answer, to help other people who have the same question to know that it works.